# Removing large strings of mixed characters

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file where every new line starts with the following bit of text.
The format is the same every time, every new line starts with 4 spaces and it ends with the (R.?/?/?) every time (different numbers in place for the question marks for every line)

```
    - Foo: on 11 december 2015 Bar (R.?/?/?)
```

I would like to remove this bit of text from every line, however, I've been having issues trying to get sed to recognize my regexes for this. I've been trying stuff like:

```
 sed 's/\n*)//g'
```

But this doesn't seem to get remove any lines from the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why would it, seds a line editor.

Comment: Will there ever be an opening-parens in the except as `(R ...)` ? If not, then `sed 's/[(].*$//' file` Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/[^)]*)//' File
```

This removes all characters till the first `)` (inclusive) from the beginning of each line.